# Java newbie - cannot find symbol - variable

Tags: java, class

let's say I have :
`public static int MIN = 0;` in a class.

and I am trying to use this constant in another class with main :
 `myVar = MIN;`

why am I getting `cannot find symbol - variable MIN` error? both classes are public and so is the constant MIN.

any help would be appreciated. thank you fellow coders

e; thank you guys, it worked!

Comment: You need to use `ClassName.MIN` in the other class (or use static imports).

Comment: Heh, couldn't find dupe. Either the search system is getting more weak or it actually isn't a dupe :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use a class constant like `MIN` from a class A, you would need to

```
import static A.MIN;
```

or you could use

```
int myVar = A.MIN;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should search on this simple thing and you would have got a lot of links,anyway try this, the where you defined

```
public static int MIN = 0;
```

try like this

```
myVar = that_class_name.MIN
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to access the value with `ClassName.MIN`, where ClassName is the name of the class which includes MIN.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the name of class that has the attribute. For do that, follow this syntax:

```
ClassName.attribute;
```

In this case the variable is static, but if you are using a class with non-static members you first have to create a object of the class and then call it, for example:

```
MyClass sampleClass = new MyClass();

sampleClass.attribute;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to type `myVar = ClassName;` instead of just `myVar = MIN;`. you also need to import the class `import ClassName.*;` or `import ClassName;`. If you import it staticly: `import static ClassName;` you can do `myVar = MIN;`;

Comment: You can't import a static variable with a normal `import` statement.

Comment: In fact I am making a library right now. A lot of things in it are static and I have no problem importing them non-statically. I just have to USE them statically.

Comment: You can import static classes, not variables.